# Writing non linear part of equation after change of coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I'm trying to write a function in Matlab (although could be in some other language) that will do the following:
I have a system of non linear equations, usually of the form
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}= ax+by+xy+x^2, \\
\frac{dy}{dt}= bx+cy+ xy+y^2.
\end{cases}
$$
I then make a change of coordinates so that the linear part is in Jordan normal form. I do this by using the inbuilt Jordan decomposition function in Matlab. My issue is this:
How can I get the program to express the non linear parts in the new variables?

Thank you

Comment: I answered to the previous one, if you change the question then someone could put me -1 points

Comment: I just edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

The linear part of your system is

$
\begin{pmatrix}
   x’ \\
   y’
\end{pmatrix}=A \begin{pmatrix}
   x\\
   y
\end{pmatrix}
$

where $A:=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
b & c
\end{pmatrix}$

that is symmetric, and so diagonalizable.

Consider the change of variables $\begin{pmatrix} z\\
u\end{pmatrix}= B \begin{pmatrix}
   x\\
   y
\end{pmatrix} $

so that

$\begin{pmatrix}
   z’ \\
   u’
\end{pmatrix}=BA \begin{pmatrix}
   x\\
   y
\end{pmatrix}= BAB^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
   z\\
   u
\end{pmatrix}
$

Now you want to diagonalize it, so you have to take $B$ such that $BAB^{-1}$ is diagonal

$B$ is the change base matrix from the standard basis to a basis of eigenvectors of $A$.

$$\det(A-\lambda I)=(a-\lambda)(c-\lambda)-b^2=\lambda^2-(a+c)\lambda+ac-b^2 $$

$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{(a+c)+/- \sqrt{(a-c)^2+4b^2}}{2}$

Now you have to find a basis of eigenvectors. I will not continue because it’s too long.

In any case at the end you will have that the initial system became

$$\begin{pmatrix}
   z’ \\
   u’
\end{pmatrix}= BAB^{-1} \begin{pmatrix}
   z\\
   u
\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix}x(z,u)y(z,u)+x(z,u)^2\\
x(z,u)y(z,u)+y(z,u)^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Where $x(z,u)$ and $y(z,u)$ are obtained by

$\begin{pmatrix}
   x\\
   y
\end{pmatrix}= B^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} z\\
u\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: Thank you! My issue is not with diagonalising though, sorry if that was unclear. I'd like to express the nonlinear parts in the new coordinates for which the linear part is diagonalised.

Comment: @annita82 give me 30 minutes and I will answer you. I’ve to take a train 

Comment: Haha ok safe trip!

Comment: @annita82 I did it 

Comment: Thank you haha, but my question really wasn't on diagonalising, but on getting the program I am trying to write de give me the expression of the non linear part. I am not asking about how to make the change of variables.